# is <math.h> for C or C++?

Tags: c++, math, logging

Im needing the natural logarithm function for use in a .cpp (c++) source file. Now, of course I can do this with a quick google search and a simple library solution. But Im a bit confused...

On the cplusplus dot com website under reference/cmath/log/ they have an example of how to use the log function, as follows

```
/* log example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* log */

int main ()
{
   double param, result;
   param = 5.5;
   result = log (param);
   printf ("log(%f) = %f\n", param, result );
   return 0;
}
```

some questions i have:

1) Why are they using

```
<stdio.h>
```

I thought this was for C and not really for C++ ?

2) Why are they using

```
<math.h>
```

I though the .h represented C header files rather than the .hpp C++ header files?

Forgetting about the use of stdio (i'll use iostream anyway) but even so by using

```
<math.h>
```

It feels like I'm writing C code and not C++ code. Im learning C++ through a taught course and the instructor covered C in the first week and then said we wont be using C again but will be using C++ from now on. I feel like I wont be able to explain myself if the teacher asks "why did you use a C header file? You are supposed to be working in C++".

Any explanations much appreciated.

Comment: For C++ use `<cmath>` rather than `<math.h>`.

Comment: A header by that name is available in both C and C++ standard libraries, and is usually the same file.

Comment: @Paul blimey your quick in responding. I saw that but, in another cmath vs math.h stackoverflow question the answer provided states "it may compile with one compiler but not with another. therefore it's a good idea to use [math.h]". Which just confuses me even more.

Comment: but why the .h and not .hpp

Comment: Most of the standard C library headers with a .h suffix have a C++ equivalent which takes care of the std namespace, adding a c prefix and dropping the .h suffix.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<math.h>` is a header specified in the C standard.  Its usage is supported in C++, but formally deprecated (which means, approximately, slated for potential removal from a future standard) by all C++ standards.    I would suggest it is unlikely to be removed from a future C++ standard, for as long as backward compatibility to C is considered important or desirable.

`<cmath>` is a header specified in the C++ standard.   It provides essentially the same functionality as in C's `<math.h>`, except that names (other than a couple of macros) reside in namespace `std`.

A similar story goes for `<stdio.h>` (C) and `<cstdio>` (C++), except that usage of stream I/O (e.g. `<iostream>`) is encouraged in C++.

Standard C++ headers never have a `.hpp` extension.   That naming convention for headers is a convention encouraged by some, but is not formally required.

Answer (score 2):

The `C++11 Standard` says:

> **D.5** C standard library headers
>
> 1 For compatibility with the C standard library and the C Unicode TR, the C++ standard library provides the 25 C headers, ...

The inclusion of these headers is stated as deprecated, meaning:

> Normative for the current edition of the Standard, but not guaranteed to be part of the Standard in future revisions.

So they are still (just) part of `C++`.

They are provided for *compatibility* which is to allow the programmer to compile programs originally written for `C` with a standard conforming `C++` compiler with little or no modification. That means things like not having to change the `#include` statements from `<stdio.h>` to `<ctsdio>`.

So the example given in `cplusplus.com` is actually standards conforming `C++` that just happens to be compatible with a `C90` and a `C99` conforming `C` compiler. Presumably they do this because the page describing the math library gives information for *both* `C` and `C++` languages following the standards for `C90`, `C99`, `C++98` and `C++11`.

So to answer the specific questions:

> 1) Why are they using
>
> ```
> <stdio.h>
> ```
>
> I thought this was for C and not really for C++ ?

It's for `C++` *compatibility* with `C`. Presumably they use it so the code will also compile on a `C90/C99` conforming `C` compiler for which the page gives specifications.

> 1) Why are they using
>
> ```
> <math.h>
> ```
>
> I though the .h represented C header files rather than the .hpp C++ header files?

No. The standard does not specify what extensions files should use. In practice many `C++` projects use `.h` as an extension for their header files.

> I feel like I wont be able to explain myself if the teacher asks "why did you use a C header file?

Given that the `C` compatibility headers are deprecated (though probably not going anywhere) I would suggest it better to use the `<cstdio>` and `<cmath>` versions. However the idea that you are somehow writing `C` code simply because of your choice of library function is wrong. If it is legal `C++` code being fed through a `C++` compiler then it is `C++`. It may be more *procedural* in character and less *object oriented* in philosophy but it is nevertheless fully `C++`. Many, many, many `C++` programs use libraries written in other languages, *especially* `C`. That doesn't make those programs somehow `C`.

Answer (score 1):

About your first qustion, stdio.h is required for the printf function used
About your second question, math.h can be used by both C and C++, but cmath will define the methods in std namespace while math.h will define those in the global namespace

Generally put, you can use C code within C++ code, there *usually* not going to be any problem with that, especially when dealing with well known libraries like math.h

Comment: Yes I understand that stdio is needed for printf but why are they doing this on a C++ reference site, surely this is C and not C++ ?

Comment: You are correct, it is C syntax and you _should_ use std::cout (iostream instead of stdlib) to print stuff when working with C++. That being said, there is no harm in using stdio in C++, it is fully supported and frankly, some people are just used to it

Comment: Also there's `cstdio` too which at least uses a bit of the `std::` namespace advantage, same as `cmath`.

Comment: @RunnerBean if you prefer you can try a different reference site like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log). I personally consider it to be cleaner and have better examples, though I haven't looked at cplusplus.com in quite a while and it might just be my preference.

Answer (score 1):

`<math.h>`(for C) and `<cmath>`(for C++) are very similar in basic usage of functions. `<cmath>` begins to differ in more advanced stages, involving templates, STL, and Object-Oriented Programming in general.

Whether you use C or C++, `<math.h>` can be used, but I don't think the opposite (`<cmath>` for C) works. I recommend `<cmath>` for C++ as it's the same as , but has more powerful OOP features.