# C++ pow() function changes behaviour when put inside a function

Tags: c++, math, gnu

I have been programming in C++ for a while now. I have seen previously that power function gives wrong answer for bigger powers due to precision issues but today while solving coding problems I saw that under the same type of parameters, pow() function gave different values when put inside a function vs when evaluated directly.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <math.h>
 using namespace std;

 long long n,d;

 long long power(long long x)
 {
    return pow(100,x);
 }

 long long powersecond(long long x)
 {
    return pow(100,(int)x);
 }

 int main()
 {
    n = 68; d = 2;
    cout << n*power(d) <<endl;        // outputs 679932
    cout << n*pow(100,d) <<endl;      // outputs 680000
    cout << n*powersecond(d) <<endl;  // outputs 679932
    cout << n*pow(100,(int)d) <<endl; // outputs 680000
    return 0;
 }
```

Notice that the answer doesn't change even after converting x to integer in powersecond() function.The answer is still 679932 even if d is int instead of long long int.
The compiler I used is gnu gcc compiler in VS Code.

Comment: No need for macros: `using ll = long long;`

Comment: There is no issue, each is resolving to a call to [std::pow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) with different types.

Comment: For C++, better to use C++ `#include <cmath>` than C-style `#include <math.h>`.  q.v. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904795/4641116

Comment: [Screenshot on this drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iTdLtf6ovfdzUDFMPOYdMMKKKvj2Q3uH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @keith What different overloads? They all end up in `pow(double, double)`, no?

Comment: I tried this with multiple compilers, it's giving the right answer, what you got is weird, have you tried to run it again ?

Comment: Yes I got wrong answer for a problem on an online judge [atcoder](https://atcoder.jp) then I saw the test cases and ran it locally and discovered this.

Comment: @Barry, really? There are overloads when the exponent is integral as is the case here for some of the code paths.

Comment: @keith [Yes, really](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow). All the integral overloads convert their arguments to `double` or `long double`.

Comment: @Barry, that's not what the documentation says.

Comment: @keith Quote: _If any argument has integral type, it is cast to `double`._

Comment: @Daniel Langr, ah yes, I thought that only applied to 7 but didn't see the the fact that 7 repalces 4-6 - thanks for correction.

Comment: @keith If in doubts, it's always best to look to the Standard: _Otherwise, if any argument of arithmetic type corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `double` **or an integer type**, then all arguments of arithmetic type corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to `double`._ [cmath.syn/2.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/c.math#cmath.syn-2.2). The quote from cppreference just stemmed from this sentence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the output of `pow` is a floating point `double`.  In your custom function you convert that output to `long long`, which will truncate if the value returned by `pow` is slightly low instead of slightly high.  See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?noredirect=1&lq=1).  When you call `pow` directly the value is kept as a `double` even after the multiplication, and output rounding gives you a more accurate result.

You expect the value returned by `pow(100,2)` to be 10000, but instead it might be 9999.99999999999 because of the way floating point works.  When converted to integer, that becomes 9999; multiplied by 68, you have 679932.

On the other hand, 9999.99999999999 multiplied by 68 becomes 679999.999999999.  That's close enough to 680000 that the output function `<<` will round it for you.  You can get a more exact figure if you apply output formatting.

Comment: Thanks for answering !! everything makes sense now.

Comment: The result of `pow(100,2)` should be representable by `double` without any rounding error, so why should any rounding occur when converted to `long long`?

Comment: @DanielLangr you don't know the mechanics of how `pow` is calculated via `double`.  Even if it's possible to represent an exact result, it could still easily be off by one LSB.

Comment: @MarkRansom But if `pow` itself calculated wrong result (rounded), then all the result would be wrong, wouldn't they? BTW I couldn't reproduce the problem with multiple compilers, so I'd like to know what is different in OP's case.

Comment: @DanielLangr `cout << double` doesn't go for the most precise representation, it uses its own rounding to hide tiny floating point errors.  It's quite sophisticated.

Comment: @DanielLangr a few years ago I fielded a question about `pow(5,2)` coming back with 24.99999something.

Comment: @user4581301 I can understand that, but if `pow(100,2)` was calculated imprecisely, I would expect the error be observable even with `double` multiplication by `n`. But you are likely right, I see the point. I would just like to see the assembly that generates the error. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @DanielLangr `pow` was just doing something weird. It might not have had any short-cuts in the logic and ran the same voodoo process for 5 to the 2 that it used for difficult stuff like pi to the e. The funny thing is if the questioner had been calling `pow` instead of `std::pow` via `using namespace std;` they never would have seen the problem. I wasn't able to figure out why that made a difference. Far as I could tell it still called `pow` at the end.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk This is the best explanation and you should turn it into a standalone answer. Two important facts — I didn't realize that 679932 equals 68 times 9999. And, that casting double into integer truncates towards zero. Now, it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I was considering making those changes, it's a good idea.  I've just been a bit busy this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Always write your own power function whenever needed. Change return type according to your requirement to avoid any kind of confusion.

```cpp
long long int power(long long int a, long long int x) {
  static long long int ans = 1;
  if (x < 0)
    return 1 / power(a, (-1 * x));
  if (x == 1)
    return a;
  if (x == 0 or a == 1)
    return 1;
  if (x & 1)
    ans = a * power((a * a), x / 2);
  else
    ans = power((a * a), x / 2);
  return ans;
}
```

Here is recursive version .You can also write iterative version.